# How to split string have multi char || on C#

Tags: c#, split, char

I have string format, example `"abc || def || igh"`.
I want to cut into: abc, def,igh, but when i try use split getting the error
"Too many characters in character literal error"
 Can somebody help me?  Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

You can use char array.Example:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', '?', ':' };
```

after

```
text.Split(delimiterChars)
```